# Extract string between /

Tags: r, regex

If I have these strings:

```
mystrings <- c("X2/D2/F4",
               "X10/D9/F4",
               "X3/D22/F4",
               "X9/D22/F9")
```

How can I extract `2,9,22,22`.  These characters are between the `/` and after the first character within the `/`.

I would like to do this in a vectorized fashion and add the new column with `transfrom` if possible with which I am familiar.

I think this regex gets me somewhere near all the characters within `\`:

```
^.*\\'(.*)'\\.*$
```

Comment: +1 for all @Arun gave me the first workable answer. I just don't work with strings enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`as.numeric(gsub("^.*D([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", mystrings))`

Answer (score 29):

```
> gsub("(^.+/[A-Z]+)(\\d+)(/.+$)", "\\2", mystrings)
[1] "2"  "9"  "22" "22"
```

You would "read" (or "parse") that regex pattern as splitting any matched string into three parts:

1) anything up to and including the first forward slash followed by a sequence of capital letters,

2) any digits(= "\d") in a sequence before the next slash and ,

3) from the next slash to the end.

And then only returning the second part....

Non-matched character strings would be returned unaltered.

Comment: +1 I did not know you could grab the second set of matches with `\\2` without a second group! Slick.

Answer (score 8):

Using `str_extract` from the `stringr` package:

```
as.numeric(str_extract(mystrings, perl('(?<=/[A-Z])[0-9]+(?=/)')))
```

Comment: @rrs It's part of a look-behind assertion. type `?regex` in the R prompt and read the last few paragraphs of the "Perl-like Regular Expressions" section.

Answer (score 8):

@Arun stole my thunder, so I'm giving my initial long-winded example.

```
cut.to.pieces <- strsplit(mystrings, split = "/")
got.second <- lapply(cut.to.pieces, "[", 2)
get.numbers <- unlist(got.second)
as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "[[:alpha:]]", replacement = "", x = get.numbers, perl = TRUE))
[1]  2  9 22 22
```

Answer (score 4):

This ended up being a compacted version of @RomanLuštrik's answer:

```
gsub("[^0-9]","",sapply(strsplit(mystrings,"/"),"[",2))
[1] "2"  "9"  "22" "22"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

```
matches <- re_matches(mystrings,
  rex(
    "/",
    any,
    capture(name = "numbers", digits)
    )
  )

as.numeric(matches$numbers)
#>[1]  2  9 22 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the package *unglue* you could do :

```r
# install.packages("unglue")
library(unglue)

unglue_vec(mystrings, "{x}/{y}/{z}", var = "y")
#> [1] "D2"  "D9"  "D22" "D22"
```

From a data frame you could use `unglue_unnest()` so no need to use `transform()`

```
df <- data.frame(col = mystrings)
unglue_unnest(df, col, "{x}/{y}/{z}", remove = FALSE)
#>         col   x   y  z
#> 1  X2/D2/F4  X2  D2 F4
#> 2 X10/D9/F4 X10  D9 F4
#> 3 X3/D22/F4  X3 D22 F4
#> 4 X9/D22/F9  X9 D22 F9

# or used unnamed subpatterns to keep only the middle value
unglue_unnest(df, col, "{=.*?}/{y}/{=.*?}", remove = FALSE)
#>         col   y
#> 1  X2/D2/F4  D2
#> 2 X10/D9/F4  D9
#> 3 X3/D22/F4 D22
#> 4 X9/D22/F9 D22
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

More info: https://github.com/moodymudskipper/unglue/blob/master/README.md